# Errors when running executable jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I get the error below when trying to run an executable jar file. The file only contains a main  with one line "System.out.println("Woo!");" and runs fine in eclipse.

I'm not sure how to read these error messages.

[image: UnsupportedClassVersionError exception trace]

(too new to post images correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiled class is in jre 1.5 and your system default jre is different(might be 1.6).

compile your code in same version of jre.

Comment: I checked eclipse and i checked my version of java and it says theyre both working for java 1.7. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Nevermind. Even after updating my java it still wanted to run in 1.5, so i just rolled back the compile version of the program and it doesnt give me that error anymore (it is now giving me a main not found error, but thats on another post)

Answer (score 3):

The error means that you have compiled the code with a higher version of java and trying to run it on a older version of jvm.

Since it says `major.minor version 51.0` it means that your compiler is java6. So you should run your program on java6 or higher.

Comment: Actually - I believe it is the other way around.  You are compiling against a newer version of Java and trying to run with an old JVM.  Ex: compiling for Java 6, but using a Java 4 JRE.

Comment: I am actually bound by my adminstrators to keep an older version of the JRE on my computer, so all i did was change the version the compiler builds the jar into.